# Storm: Error on initialization of server mk-supervisor- Required field 'serialized_parts' is unset error

Tags: apache-storm

I attempted to install the latest version of storm, storm 0.10.beta1 [apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1.tar.gz](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/storm/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1/apache-storm-0.10.0-beta1.tar.gz)

And use the following supervisord script to start supervisor, but I got the **TProtocolException: Required field 'serialized_parts' is unset error**.

```
[program:storm-supervisor]
command=/home/prod/softwares/storm/bin/storm supervisor
autostart=true  
autorestart=true  
startsecs=10 
startretries=999  
kill_as_group=true
```

**Storm.yaml**

```
storm.zookeepereeper.servers:
        - "192.168.10.30"
        storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
        storm.local.dir: "localdir"
        nimbus.host: "192.168.10.30"
        supervisor.slots.ports:
               - 6700
        ui.port: 8080
```

Anybody know why such error occurred? The exception call stack as following shown

```
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.protocol.TProtocolException: Required field 'serialized_parts' is unset! Struct:LocalStateData(serialized_parts:null)
        at backtype.storm.generated.LocalStateData.validate(LocalStateData.java:336) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at backtype.storm.generated.LocalStateData$LocalStateDataStandardScheme.read(LocalStateData.java:403) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at backtype.storm.generated.LocalStateData$LocalStateDataStandardScheme.read(LocalStateData.java:364) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at backtype.storm.generated.LocalStateData.read(LocalStateData.java:310) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at org.apache.thrift7.TDeserializer.deserialize(TDeserializer.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at org.apache.thrift7.TDeserializer.deserialize(TDeserializer.java:67) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.partialDeserializeLatestVersion(LocalState.java:100) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at backtype.storm.utils.LocalState.partialSnapshot(LocalState.java:114) ~[storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        ... 14 more
2015-06-25 09:18:33.392 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error on initialization")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error on initialization")
        at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:332) [storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__5519$mk_supervisor__5546.doInvoke(supervisor.clj:495) [storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:436) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_launch.invoke(supervisor.clj:782) [storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$_main.invoke(supervisor.clj:813) [storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor.main(Unknown Source) [storm-core-0.10.0-beta1.jar:0.10.0-beta1]
```

Comment: I just ran into this issue as well did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may me that you have left overs in your /storm-local directory from an interrupted run. Restart your supervisor after you delete /storm-local directory.